# How to do source cleanup / code formatting (defined in eclipse) using ant task

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, naming-conventions

We have a defined a set of rules in Eclipse  for code formatting and clean up. 
is there a way to run the code clean up using ant task ?

I know that there are tools like [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) but these tool have thier own configurations and rules, and I don't want to maintain 2 sets of rules.

I'm looking for an ant task that will use the same exact configuration and rules  defined for eclipse code formatting / clean up

-- Thanks
       Yonatan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using the Java -> Editor -> Save Actions to enable reformatting on save instead?

Comment: This is almost what I wanted (as it still part of the configuration is different from the source clean up configuration).
It is a simple and straightforward solution
Thanks

Comment: You are welcome.  I don't understand your statement about part of the configuration different from the source clean up configuration?

Answer (score 3):

This link has what you are looking for I believe: [Batch Code Formatting using Eclipse Code Formatter, but without Eclipse.](http://www.nirving.com/2007/06/01/batch-code-formatting-using-eclipse-code-formatter-but-without-eclipse/)

Comment: Updated link: http://www.peterfriese.de/formatting-your-code-using-the-eclipse-code-formatter/

Answer (score 0):

I used [Jalopy](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/) as Eclipse plugin.

Take a look [at his ant integration](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/existing/plugin-ant.html).

Comment: Jalopy will certainly format the code during an ant build, but Jalopy has an entirely separate configuration to the Eclipse formatter. It is (in my experience) impossible to make the two configurations achieve exactly the same results, so you get different source depending on where it was formatted. This is a nightmare for dif tools

Comment: I agree with you. But why don't use both Jalopy Eclipse Plugin and Jalopy Ant task? same rules, same formatting?

Comment: Sometimes you don't have control over your code formatting configuration. In such a case, you would want to reuse the original code formatter, not a new one.